# RS-232C with phone connector

Tags: rs232

I found the following picture of the connectors of a monitor.

[image]

The serial connector looks like a phone connector. But I know only the D-sub and RJ connectors for serial ports. Can anybody tell me the name of the specification for this cabling?

Comment: Premanufactured connectors appear to be available for this: https://www.amazon.com/SF-Cable-Female-Serial-Cable-6/dp/B004T9BBJC - also, try your monitor's manual. It might help if you said what the manufacturer was.

Comment: @pjc50 Searching for "sf db9" led me to this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/190447/voltage-conversion-in-pc-serial-db9-port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a 3.5mm audio jack also called a phone connector as you say.  It's common to use a cheaper connector to add (an often unused by the consumer) serial port.  Anyway if you want to use it, grab an old audio cable or a pair of headphones and cut the cable.  Or you could get yourself a 3.5mm audio plug from digikey.  Then just ohm it out to find gnd and then connect to either a scope or a serial device and try to figure out which pin is gnd and which is receive.  There's only a couple of combinations of RX, TX and GND.

Comment: So you think the port is proprietary and no standard does exist for this kind of cabling?

Comment: Proprietary is a strong word here.  They probably just hooked up RX, TX, and GND to one of three conductors in that phone jack.  It's surely some version of RS232 but the voltage levels may be closer to 3.3V (a guess).  If you can generate some RS232 traffic all this and baud rate is easily determined with a scope.

Comment: The image is from a "LG 43UD79-B". I did not bought it. I am just wondering if I can use the port with a Raspi or something similar.

Comment: Looking in the manual for that monitor you can see it includes an RS232 adapter that plugs into that port and gives you the normal RS232 style connector.

Comment: Also, it looks like on Page 36, it describes the serial setup and capability of this interface.  43UD79_43UD79T_ENG-US_OWM.pdf